# How to know size of flv size from url?

Tags: php, size, flv

If I know flv video,
for example:

```
www.domain.com/video.flv
```

I can't use "filesize" because it doesn't able to check size from external url, right?
So, how can I know his size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CURL to get the headers of a remote file, including the size of a file.

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/video.flv';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$headers = curl_exec($ch);

$size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

curl_close($ch);
```

Setting CURLOPT_NOBODY to true, makes CURL not download the body of a requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CURL to send a HTTP HEAD request to the URL you want to know the file size of.  The server should send back a content-length header in its response, listing the filesize in octets (bytes).

The server isn't necessarially going to actually send the content-length header though.  If it doesn't, then your only option is to actually download the file in full.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use "filesize" because it doesn't able to check size from external url, right?

Yes it [can](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) do that, but it's a bit ridiculous to do so, because the url wrappers will first download the file and then check its size.

You could do a HEAD request, which will ask the server for the file size without requesting the file data.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant snippet here:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1207